# Google Places API querying specific hours in IOS SDK?

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I have read on the **Google Places iOS SDK** docs that when a place is query'd by the place ID, you can only retrieve the "openNowStatus" of said place, and not the actual hours of said place (wether it be for the current day, or week). See here for [iOS Place Report Docs](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place.html#property-documentation). Whereas the Google Places Web API, includes a flurry of open/closed information - see [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults).

My question is - Would it is possible to get those same details about a place (regarding the hours of operation) through the Google Places iOS SDK? I referenced this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463396/google-place-api-how-to-retrieve-opening-hours), but of course that is in regards to the web API and not the iOS SDK.

If anyone would be able to help me answer this question I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: Any answer for this @Google? Still have not gotten an update about this.